# Want to flip directory structure

Tags: bash

I have a directory structure that looks like:

```
+ /root
    + a
        + 1/1/2016.csv
        + 1/2/2016.csv
        + 12/31/2017.csv
    + b
        + 1/1/2016.csv
        + 1/2/2016.csv
        + 12/31/2017.csv
    + c
        + 1/1/2016.csv
        + 1/2/2016.csv
        + 12/31/2017.csv
```

And so on.

I'd like to switch them to be:

```
+ root
    + 1/1/2016
        + a.csv
        + b.csv
        + c.csv
    + 1/2/2016
        + a.csv
        + b.csv
        + c.csv
```

All directories will have the same number of files, so its a m x n directory structure and I want to switch it to a n x m directory structure.

In pseudo code:

```
For each file_name in a: # since all directories have same file_names
    initialize file_name_without_csv
    create_directory, file_name_without_csv, without csv
    for each directory in root:
        new_file_name = directory + ".csv"
        move root/directory/file_name to root/file_name_without_csv/new_file_name
```

Is there some easy way to do this, or just write some python code to do this?

I know I can actually just write code to do this, but figured there might be an official way to do this. Sort of like a transpose of the directory structure.

Comment: Hmm, Is there a system that allows a slash in filenames? I don't think Unixes or Windows do. So, do you have files like `/root/a/1/1/2016.csv` with the directories for the month and day in between, or do the file names have some other date separator?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

1. Source it.
2. 'testenv' to setup a testdir with test files.
3. 'test' and inspect if satisfy your needs.

It uses ln to avoid unnecessary copying. If you want to be on the safe side, remove th rm -rf at the end of 'test' to inspect first and rm manually yourself (I recommend it). I leave some echoes there for easier evaluation.

```
#setup test env
testenv(){
    mkdir swaptest
    cd swaptest
    mkdir {a,b,c}
    touch {a,b,c}/{1_1_2016.csv,1_2_2016.csv,12_31_2017.csv}
}

swap(){
    for d in $(find . * -type d -depth 1); do
        echo "dir $d"
        for f in $(find "$d" -type f -depth 1); do
            echo "file $f"
            filename=$(basename "$f")
            filename_strip=${filename%.*}
            filename_ext=${filename##*.}

            if [[ ! -d "$filename_strip" ]]; then
                mkdir "$filename_strip"
            fi
            echo "filename $filename"
            echo "filename_strip $filename_strip"
            ln "$f" "$filename_strip"/$(basename "$d")."$filename_ext"
        done
        rm -rf "$d"
    done

}
```